# jQuery Validation Engine : Change Date Format

Tags: javascript, jquery, regex, date, datepicker

**My Datepicker code**

```
$(function(){ 

         $( "#task_start_date").datepicker({
         dateFormat: 'dd-M-yy',
         showOn: 'button',
         buttonImage :image_us,
         buttonImageOnly: true
        });
});
```

**HTML Input:**

```
<input type="text" class="form-control validate[required,custom[date]]" name="task_start_date" id="task_start_date" />
```

**JS function for Correct Date input validation:**

```
"date": {                    
                    //  Check if date is valid by leap year
            "func": function (field) {
                    var pattern = new RegExp(/^(\d{4})[\/\-\.](0?[1-9]|1[012])[\/\-\.](0?[1-9]|[12][0-9]|3[01])$/);
                    var match = pattern.exec(field.val());
                    if (match == null)
                       return false;

                    var year = match[1];
                    var month = match[2]*1;
                    var day = match[3]*1;                   
                    var date = new Date(year, month - 1, day); // because months starts from 0.

                    return (date.getFullYear() == year && date.getMonth() == (month - 1) && date.getDate() == day);
                },                      
             "alertText": "* Invalid date, must be in YYYY-MM-DD format"
                },
```

Here the `regex` expects `YYYY-MM-DD (2014-11-26)` format but we are using `dd-M-yy(01-MAR-12)` format.

**Regex Tried:**

```
/^(0?[1-9]|[12][0-9]|3[01])[\/\-](0?[1-9]|1[012])[\/\-]\d{4}$/
```

The above `regex` did not work. How can I change the `regex` to match the expected datepicker output. The value inserted in DB is `01-MAR-12` and not `2014-11-26`.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> ^(0?[1-9]|[12][0-9]|3[01])[-][A-Z]{3}[-]\d{2}$

This should do the trick. The regex you tried was for the format of dd/mm/yyyy or dd-mm-yyyy.

Comment: For `25-Nov-2014`, it still shows the validation. * Invalid date, must be in `YYYY-MM-DD` format. `var pattern = new RegExp(/^(0?[1-9]|[12][0-9]|3[01])[-][A-Z]{3}[-]\d{2}$/);`

Comment: I guess I misunderstood your question. I thought you wanted a regex to match the format `01-MAR-12` but if you want it to match `25-Nov-2014` the correct regex should be `^(0?[1-9]|[12][0-9]|3[01])[-][A-Za-z]{3}[-]\d{4}$` - note the added `a-z` after `A-Z`. the `[A-Za-z]` means it will match as well capitals as normal characters. If you wish it to only accept capitals (like in `01-MAR-2014`) you will need to replace `[A-Za-z]` by `[A-Z]`. [Succesfully tested](http://regexr.com/39vfn)

Answer (score 0):

Try this (not tested):

```
(?:0[1-9]|1[0-9]|2[0-9]|3[01])-(?:JAN|FEB|MAR|APR|MAY|JUN|JUL|AUG|SEP|OCT|NOV|DEC)-\d{2}
```

- `(?:0[1-9]|1[0-9]|2[0-9]|3[01])` : match 01 to 09, 10 to 19, 20 to 29, 30 to 31. But Feb doesnt have anything over 29 so how you deal with that we not be regex based
- `-` : match hypen
- `(?:JAN|FEB|MAR|APR|MAY|JUN|JUL|AUG|SEP|OCT|NOV|DEC)` : matches month
- `-` : match hypen
- `-\d{2}` : match any two digits in any order

You can shrink the regex but I dont have time right now.

Answer (score 0):

**Use this one**

```js
"date": {                    
  // Check if date is valid by leap year
  "func": function (field) {
  var pattern = new RegExp(/^(0?[1-9]|[12][0-9]|3[01])[\/\-\.](0?[1-9]|1[012])[\/\-\.](\d{4})$/);
 var match = pattern.exec(field.val());
 if (match == null)
    return false;                     

 var year = match[3];
 var month = match[2]*1;
 var day = match[1]*1;     
 var date = new Date(year, month - 1, day); // because months starts from 0.

  return (date.getFullYear() == year && date.getMonth() == (month - 1) && date.getDate() == day);
  },                  
  "alertText": "* Invalid date, must be in dd-mm-yyyy format"
},
```