# jQuery Validation Engine : Change Regex for Date Format dd-M-yy

Tags: javascript, jquery, regex, validation

JS script for validating date format:

```
"date": {                    
                    //  Check if date is valid by leap year
            "func": function (field) {
                    //var pattern = new RegExp(/^(\d{4})[\/\-\.](0?[1-9]|1[012])[\/\-\.](0?[1-9]|[12][0-9]|3[01])$/);
                    var pattern = new RegExp(/([12]\d|0[1-9]|3[0-1])-(Jan|Feb|Mar|Apr|May|Jun|Jul|Aug|Sep|Oct|Nov|Dec)-\d{4}/);
                    var match = pattern.exec(field.val());
                    if (match == null)
                       return false;

                    /*var year = match[1];
                    var month = match[2]*1;
                    var day = match[3]*1;*/
                    var year = match;
                    var month = match[2];
                    var day = match[3];

                    var date = new Date(day, month - 1, year); // because months starts from 0.
                    return (date.getFullYear() == year && date.getMonth() == (month - 1) && date.getDate() == day);
                },                      
             "alertText": "* Invalid date, must be in DD-MM-YYYY format"
                },
```

Here, the regex has been changed to work with the format `dd-M-yy`. The regex is valid but it still shows the validation error when datepicker input is true.

How can I make the date format as `dd-M-yy` i.e `26-Nov-2014` and it gives no validations if the format is correct ?

Thanks.

Comment: In your question to want dd-M-yy to be valid but in your `alertText` you show the message with format `YYY-MM-DD`...

Comment: @VDesign, question updated. Validation error will only come if it does not match the regex.

Comment: can you create a jsfiddle with your code so we can test this and see what is going wrong?

Comment: This describes all - `http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27142916/jquery-validation-engine-change-date-format`

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15491894/regex-to-validate-date-format-dd-mm-yyyy/26972181#26972181

Comment: @VDesign : JSFiddle - `http://jsfiddle.net/mw56tnej/11/`.

Answer (score 0):

**Try this**:

```
var pattern = new RegExp(/([12]\d|0[1-9]|3[0-1])-(Jan|Feb|Mar|Apr|May|Jun|Jul|Aug|Sep|Oct|Nov|Dec)-(\d{4})/);
var match = pattern.exec(field.val());
if (match == null)
 return false;

var months = ["Jan", "Feb", "Mar", "Apr", "May", "Jun", "Jul", "Aug", "Sep", "Oct", "Nov", "Dec"]
var year = match[3];
var month = match[2];
var day = match[1];

var date = new Date(day, month - 1, year); // because months starts from 0.
return (date.getFullYear() == year && date.getMonth() == months.indexOf(month) && date.getDate() == day);
```

**http://jsfiddle.net/mw56tnej/12/**

Comment: It still shows the validation error. Datepicker input is `$(function(){ 
    
   $( "#task_start_date").datepicker({
                 dateFormat: 'dd-M-yy'
        });` and class is `class="form-control validate[required,custom[date]]"`

Comment: could you create a jsfiddle with your code? I use pattern.exec("26-Nov-2014"), it return ["26-Nov-2014", "26", "Nov", "2014"].

Comment: Yes the code seems correct, but can not figure out why its still giving validation even on expected input.

Comment: Maybe you should create a jsfiddle, I really don't know what is going wrong. Thanks.

Comment: `var isOk = (date.getFullYear() == year && date.getMonth() == months.indexOf(month) && date.getDate() == day);
                                alert(isOk);` gives me `false`